# How to have zero or one of and object in a class?

Tags: java, null

I want a class A, and I want the relation that A can have zero or one X.

So I wrote this class:

```
public class A {
    private X x = null;

    public A() {}
    public A(X x) { this.x = x; }

    public boolean hasX() { 
       if(x==null) 
          return false; 
       return true; 
    }
    public void setX(X x) { this.x = x; }
    public X getX() { return x; }
}
```

But I get the feeling that I have got something wrong here. From what I have heard, you should avoid using null like this. But I am not sure how to do it. Is this the correct or recommended way to handle this?

Comment: Can't you define x as a X[1]?

Comment: @A.Rashad I guess I could, but it feels very workaroundish

Answer (score 5):

As of Java 8, this is best handled via the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) type:

```
public class A {
    private Optional<X> x = Optional.empty();

    public A() {}
    public A(X x) { this.x = Optional.of(x); }

    public void setX(X x) { this.x = Optional.ofNullable(x); }
    public Optional<X> getX() { return x; }
}
```

The use of `Optional.ofNullable(...)` means that the value can be "unset" (to empty).

Answer (score 3):

Alternately always have one. Use a Null Object.

ie.

```
class NullX extends/implements X
{
    //implement with noops
}
```

Now always assign the value an object. This has the advantage of obviating any null, or has a checks. It is a variable, it isn't null, and it can be interacted with without surprise.

Obviously this `NullX` must implement the interface and the expectations correctly. This does preclude some interfaces from having a null implementation, and may even make several null implementations possible.